# Inserting account creation date from MongoDB into Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js

I'm currently using MongoDB, NodeJS, and Handlebars and trying to convert `user .id` into a timestamp, then putting that timestamp into my HTML.

Right now, I can show the `user.id` on my website by writing `{{ user.id }}`, and I have a function that changes the id into a date:

```
var dateFromObjectId = function (objectId) {
    return new Date(parseInt(objectId.substring(0, 8), 16) * 1000);
};
```

However, I'm having trouble piecing these two bits of information together to show the date on the website.

Any help would be appreciated; thanks!

Comment: can you please show the code where you are rendering handlebar file

Answer (score 0):

You need to create handlebars [helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('toDate', function(objectId, options) {
    return new Date(parseInt(objectId.toString().substring(0, 8), 16) * 1000);
});
```

and pass object id as an argument to it:

```
<p><b>Created at:</b> {{#toDate '58a4dd700000000000000000'}}{{/toDate}}</p>
```

So what you will see will be:

**Created at:** Thu Feb 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0100

Assuming you are passing user MongoDB document from server in this form:

```
{
    user: {
      _id: ObjectId("58a62ef00000000000000000"),
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe"
    }
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>First name: {{user.first_name}}</li>
  <li>Last name: {{user.first_name}}</li>
  <li>Created at: {{#toDate user._id}}{{/toDate}}</li>
</ul>
```

Try it out [here](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/).